# PDF generation using getContent or getContectAsPdf not working in Community but works in salesforce lightning app

Tags: apex, visualforce, lightning, aura

I have tried using below methods and have also tried to get content of vf page using API but I get following errors:

1) Using get content like in below code: The file is corrupted.
2) Fetching content as API shows error as: "Callout loop exception"
3) Below methods works when I used standalone lightning app.

lightning page displayed on the community (Pasting here java script controller function which is called on button click)::::

```
({
downloadExcelFile : function(component) { 
    var action = component.get("c.getExcelFileAsBase64String");
    var self = this;
    action.setParams({
        contactId: '0030o00003Et6QiAAJ'
    });
    action.setCallback(this, function(action){
        console.log(action.getState());
        var state = action.getState();
        if(state == 'SUCCESS') {
            let downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
            console.log('action.getReturnValue() >> '+action.getReturnValue());
               downloadLink.href = "data:application/pdf;base64,"+action.getReturnValue();
               downloadLink.download = "filename.pdf";
               downloadLink.click();
        }
    }); 
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
}
```

})

Controller to call the simple vf page to show contacts records in pdf document generated using renderAs:::::

```
public class ExcelController {
@AuraEnabled 
public static String getExcelFileAsBase64String(Id contactId) {
    PageReference FA_page = new PageReference(System.URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl()+'/apex/excelfilepage');
    PageReference excelPage = Page.excelfilepage;
    excelPage.getParameters().put('cid',contactId);
    Blob excelBlob = excelPage.getContent();
    String base64Excel = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(excelBlob);
    return base64Excel;
}
```

}

Comment: Is given visualforce page accessible in community? What happens if you just open it from community via direct URL?

Comment: I added a lightning component which has a button. Once its clicked the visual force page gets rendered. I have provided access to vf page on community.